# Slf4j LoggerFactory.getLogger and sonarqube

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube, slf4j

What is the correct way to initialize Slf4j  LoggerFactory.getLogger?
I have in my code

```
static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

But sonarqube code analysis marks this code as major error:
"Rename this constant name to match the regular expression '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'"

What is wrong?

Comment: We have this exact same code in most of our classes. For consistency, I'm arguing to change it to uppercase LOGGER like all the other `static final` variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants (static final) variables are generally in upper case in Java. So you can either:

- ignore the comment in this particular case (it is not unusual to use small caps for the logger)
- rename `logger` into something else, for example `LOG`